# How to toggle class of element, but remove class if clicking an element with class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to toggle the "active" class when the img element is clicked. But when clicking an element with the class of "active," I'd like for it to be removed.

Here's the JS I'm working with currently:

```
$('.employee_mugshot').click(function() {
      $(".employee_mugshot").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Here's my full example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickbeeson/6ec2K/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be `toggleClass()`, just make sure you don't remove the class from the currently clicked element, as then the class would always be added

```
$('.employee_mugshot').click(function() {
      $(".employee_mugshot").not(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ec2K/1/)

Comment: Fing A you're fast! Where can I learn more about the `not(this)` part of your code?

Comment: Read the documentation for [**not**](https://api.jquery.com/not/), but all it does is exclude `this` so the class isn't removed on the current element, as toggleClass would then always add the class etc.